# Excel and Visio Unattended Accounts

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel-services, service-application, service, visio-services

What are the purposes of the Excel and Visio Unattended Accounts? Both services are used in the farm. I am just interested in knowing why are there dedicated for these?

Do they set the application up or do they do something after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main reason to use these accounts is security, it protect against unauthorized access to the external data sources from client computers.

- Unattended accounts are low-privilege domain account that are store in Secure store services and used to connect to external datasources.
- this service account provide equal data access to all authorized users.
- These accounts not running any application pool inside the SharePoint
  rather these are connecting the external data sources for Excel,
  Visio or performance point service.

[SharePoint Server 2013 - The Unattended Service Account](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-server-2013-the-unattended-service-account)